# Why I encounter this error in ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-arrayadapter

I already search for everything but I don't know where did I go wrong. I just follow the tutorials in adding items in the spinner from JSON data

Error:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
<init>(Context, Int, Array<(out) String!>) where T = String for constructor ArrayAdapter<T : Any!>(context: Context, resource: Int, objects: Array<(out) T!>) defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter
<init>(Context, Int, Int)   where T = String for    constructor ArrayAdapter<T : Any!>(context: Context, resource: Int, textViewResourceId: Int) defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter
<init>(Context, Int, (Mutable)List<String!>)   where T = String for    constructor ArrayAdapter<T : Any!>(context: Context, resource: Int, objects: (Mutable)List<T!>) defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter
```

My Code

```
var all_names = ArrayList<String>()
for (data in lst_member.members){
     val mn = if (data.MN == "null") "" else data.MN
     val name = data.FN +" "+ data.LN
     all_names.add(name)
}

val arrayAdapter : ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, all_names)


val spinner : Spinner = findViewById(R.id.member_lst)
```

Comment: check the params of  arrayadapter constructor.

Comment: you need to specify if this is from an activity or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the context - you need to send the activity

```
val arrayAdapter : ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter<String>(MyActivity.activity,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, all_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharone Lev is correct. But the answer to correct it is different from what he told in my code:

`val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this@MainActivity, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems)`

Normally it is not a problem to use "this", as it is the object of MyActivity, but if this ArrayAdapter() is inside another class, then "this" does not mean MyActivity, but the inner class object and cause problem. So just change it  or follows the prompt of IDE.